# Graph doesn't appear to help the browser cache profile images

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

When making a request to retrieve a user's profile photo (of a specific size) using the beta API, the Graph returns the photo, with a matching ETag:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<email address>/photos/48x48/$value

Response headers:
Cache-Control:private
...
ETag:"5743BC5B"
...etc
```

On subsequent requests for this same resource, the browser correctly sends the `If-None-Match:"5743BC5B"` header, but the server responds with a `200` and the full photo in the response body instead of the `304` I would expect. The headers of the response contain the same ETag again i.e. `ETag:"5743BC5B"`.

It would be preferable for the server to allow the browser to cache the image properly.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your API request?
In my case I'm using Restangular lib and setting 'cache: true' in HttConfig makes the browser cache the server response. All subsequent requests for that photo are read from memory.